# How to display column name for rownumber column in Jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I have enabled 'rownumbers' property to display row numbers. Table is displaying the row numbers properly, but column name space is blank.

I want to display name 'Row Num' to that column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setLabel` to change the text in the column header. The name of the column added by `rownumbers: true` is `"rn"`:

```js
$("#grid").jqGrid("setLabel", "rn", "Nr.");
```

You can use `rownumWidth` parameter to specify the width of the column.